# Cannot find document when searching for field with Id using Java API in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a field which contains forward slashes. I'm trying to execute this Query:

```
QueryBuildres.termQuery("id", QueryParser.escape("/my/field/val"))
```

and I cannot get any results. When I'm looking for 'val' only, then I get the proper results. Any ideas why is that happening? Of course without escaping it also doesn't return the results.

**UPDATE**
so QP.escape parses string properly, but when request goes to elasticsearch it's double escaped

```
[2015-07-10 01:53:00,063][WARN ][index.search.slowlog.query] [Aaa AA] [index_name][4] took[420.8micros], took_millis[0], types[page], stats[], search_type[QUERY_THEN_FETCH], total_shards[5], source[{"query":{"term":{"pageId":"\\/path\\/and\\/testestest"}}}], extra_source[],
```

**UPDATE 2**: It works when I'm using querystring, but I wouldn't like to user that and type everything by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason why I didn't get any results is the default index which I had created.

I didn't specified mapping for my field, so ElasticSearch didn't treated my field.

In ElasticSearch documentation I read, that during the analysis process, elastic search splits the string into words, lower-case them and do some other stuff. 
In my case my "/path/in/my/field" was splitted into four fields:
path
in
my
field

So when I was searching for "pageId:/path/in/my/field" I didn't get any results because pageId in fact didn't contained it.

To solve the issue I had to add proper mapping to pageId field, which didn't do any preprocessing (instead of four words, now I have one "/path/in/my/field")

Links to docs:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use _id instead of Id

Comment: no, it's not the issue. Property name is completely different